# zend/ajax related problems with dynamically adding a row

Tags: jquery, mysql, zend-framework

I have 3 tables which consists of inputs to be selected and a 4th one which has the id's of the 3 tables as foreign keys inside that table, the is also two columns with inputs in it.The 4 tables are dependet on each other. I use them with dropdowns e.g select continent dropwns autofills, country/ "province/state" / city etc and the is also a 5th table which stores this information. I want to know how can i take those selected variables and save them in that 5th table. Using zend/ajax/jquery

Im maintaing an old database but creating a new application for it they used pure php then and trully speaking my brain feels fogged.
I keep getting this error:933' was not found in the haystack/ I think it has to do with validation

here's my code

Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add').click(function(){
          $.ajax({
               url:'<?php echo $this->baseURL()?>/ajax/postsic',
               type:'post',
               data:{'division':$('#div_des').val(),'majorgroup':$('#mgrp_desc').val(),'group':$('#grp_desc').val(),'sic description':$('#sic_description').val()},       
               success:function(data){
                 $('#t2').append(data);

              }
          });
    });
    });

    </script>
```

actioncontrollerajax

```
public function postsicAction()
{
    $form = new Form_SmmeDetails5();       
    $this->view->form = $form;

    if(!$form->isValid($_POST)) {
        $values=$form->getValues();

        $mdlSmme = new Model_Smmesic();
        $results = $mdlSmme->getSelected($selected); 

        $returndata ='<tr>';
        $returndata .='<td>'.$div_code.'</td>';
        $returndata .='<td>'.$mgrp_code.'</td>';
        $returndata .='<td>'.$grp_code.'</td>';
        $returndata .='<td>'.$sic_code.'</td>';

        $returndata .='<tr>';

        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();

        echo $returndata;

        exit;
        if($form->isValid($_POST)) {
        } else {
            $form->populate($formData);
        }
    }
}
```

actioncontroller register for the form/dropdowns

```
public function register5Action()
{
    $this->view->headScript()->appendFile('/js/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js');
     $form = new Application_Form_SmmeDetails5();

    //$form->submit->setLabel('Finish');
    $this->view->form = $form;

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if ($form->isValid($formData)) {                

            $sector_name = $form->getValue('sector_name');

            $div_desc = $form->getvalue ('div_desc');
            $mgrp_code = $form->getvalue ('mgrp_code');
            $grp_code = $form->getvalue ('grp_code');
            $sic_description = $form->getvalue ('sic_description'); 
            $description= $form->getvalue ('description');
            $comments = $form->getvalue ('comments');
            $core_product = $form->getvalue ('core_product');     


            //$sectors = new Application_Model_DbTable_Sectors();
            //$sectors->smmedetails5sectors($sector_name);

            //$smmesic = new Model_SmmeDetails5();
            //$smmesic ->smmedetails5smmesic ($div_desc, $mgrp_code, $grp_code, $sic_description, $description, $comments, $core_product);

            //$division = new Application_Model_DbTable_Division();
            //$division->smmedetails5division($div_desc);

            $this->redirect('/admin/index');
        } else {
            $form->populate($formData);
        }
    }
}
```

model smmesic

```
public function getSelected($selected) 
{
    $select = $this ->select()
                        ->from('division')
                        ->where('id = ?', $div_code);

    $select = $this ->select()
                        ->from('majorgroup')
                        ->where('id = ?', $mgrp_code);

    $select = $this ->select()
                        ->from('group')
                        ->where('id  = ?', $grp_code);

    $select = $this ->select()
                        ->from('siccode')
                        ->where('id = ?', $sic_code);   

    return $this->fetchAll($select);
}
```

my form

```
<?php

class Application_Form_SmmeDetails5 extends Zend_Form
{

    public function init()
    {
        //$required = new Zend_Validate_NotEmpty ();
        //$required->setType ($required->getType() |  Zend_Validator_NotEmpty::NotEmpty );


        $this->setName('smmedetails5')
             ->setAttribs(array('class' => 'new_user_form'));
        $sector_id = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('sector_id');

        $sector_name = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('sector_name');     
        $sector_name ->setLabel('Sector')
                ->addMultiOption('--Select One--', '--Select One--');
                //->addValidators (array ($required));

        $mdlSectors = new Model_Sectors();
        $sectors = $mdlSectors->getSectors();       
        foreach ($sectors as $sector)
        {
            $sector_name->addMultiOption($sector->sector_id, $sector->sector_name);
        }  

        $sector_name->addDecorator(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div','class' => 'col-md-12 field-box'))
               ->addDecorators(array(array('HtmlTag',array('tag' => 'dd', 'class' => 'ui-select span5'))));


        $search = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('search');
        $search->setLabel('Search SIC Code:');


        $search->addDecorator(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div','class' => 'col-md-12 field-box'));           
        $search->setAttribs(array('class' => 'col-md-9 form-control')); 


        $div_desc = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('div_desc');       
        $div_desc  ->setLabel('Division')
                ->addMultiOption('--Select One--', '--Select One--');

        $mdlDivision = new Model_Division();
        $divisions = $mdlDivision->getdivisions();          
        foreach ($divisions as $division)
        {
            $div_desc->addMultiOption($division->div_code, $division->div_desc);
        } 

        $div_desc->addDecorator(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div','class' => 'col-md-12 field-box'))
             ->addDecorators(array(array('HtmlTag',array('tag' => 'dd', 'class' => 'ui-select span5'))));       


        $mgrp_desc = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('mgrp_desc');     
        $mgrp_desc  ->setLabel('Major Group')
                ->addMultiOption('--Select One--', '--Select One--');

        //$mdlMajorGroup = new Model_MajorGroup();
        //$majorgroups = $mdlMajorGroup->getmajorgroups();          
        //foreach ($majorgroups as $majorgroup)
        //{
            //$mgrp_desc->addMultiOption($majorgroup->mgrp_code, $majorgroup->mgrp_desc);
        //} 

        $mgrp_desc->addDecorator(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div','class' => 'col-md-12 field-box'))
             ->addDecorators(array(array('HtmlTag',array('tag' => 'dd', 'class' => 'ui-select span5'))));


        $grp_desc = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('grp_desc');       
        $grp_desc  ->setLabel('Group')
                ->addMultiOption('--Select One--', '--Select One--');

        //$mdlGroup = new Model_Group();
        //$groups = $mdlGroup->getgroups();         
        //foreach ($groups as $group)
        //{
            //$grp_desc->addMultiOption($group->grp_code, $group->grp_desc);
        //} 

        $grp_desc->addDecorator(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div','class' => 'col-md-12 field-box'))
             ->addDecorators(array(array('HtmlTag',array('tag' => 'dd', 'class' => 'ui-select span5')))); 


        $sic_description = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('sic_description');     
        $sic_description  ->setLabel('Sic Description')
                ->addMultiOption('--Select One--', '--Select One--');

        //$mdlSicCode = new Model_SicCode();
        //$siccodes = $mdlSicCode->getsiccodes();       
        //foreach ($siccodes as $siccode)
        //{
            //$sic_description->addMultiOption($siccode->id, $siccode->sic_description);
        //} 

        $sic_description->addDecorator(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div','class' => 'col-md-12 field-box'))
             ->addDecorators(array(array('HtmlTag',array('tag' => 'dd', 'class' => 'ui-select span5')))); 


        $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
        $submit->setLabel('+Add');
        $submit->setAttrib('smmeid', 'submitbutton')
            ->setAttrib('class', 'btn-flat primary btn-next')
            ->setAttrib('style','float:left;')
            ->addDecorator(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div','class' => 'col-md-6 field-box','style' => 'width: 50%;'));

        $this->addElements(array($sector_name, $search, $div_desc, $mgrp_desc, $grp_desc, $sic_description, $description, $comments, $core_product, $submit));
}
}
```

here are some pictures
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could be a Problem with Zend_Form. 
If you use the inArray Validator it does not know the provided values. Try to disable it on the fields.

```
$field->setRegisterInArrayValidator(false);
```

Comment: I tried it seemed to work but it does not help and add the row of the selected inputs instead it redirets to the home page with out me clicking the next button